# How can I rearrange the beginning an end of a char* (Index wise) without actually changing it?

Tags: objective-c, c, char, permutation

I have a char* string1 = "HELLOPEOPLE", and I have another char* portion = string+5. So portion points to the location in memory of "PEOPLE". My question is how can I get portion to be "PEOPLEHELLO" without changing string1.

I am asking this because I working on the cyclic permutations for the Burrows Wheeler Transform. For example is to get a matrix like this from the word PLAY (Example word).

```
PLAY
YPLA
AYPL
LAYP
```

Is there any way I can get YPLA without changing the the PLAY, just using indexes (references to points in memory)
?

Comment: Are you allowed to allocate a new string?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

You can, however, print `portion` and the first 5 characters of `string1`

```
printf("%s%5.5s\n", portion, string1);
```

Or print `portion` and the part of `string1` before `portion`

```
int len = portion - string1;
printf("%s%*.*s\n", portion, len, len, string1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you create a new string and copy in it the portions in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strncpy` and `strncat`, from the C standard library:

```
 char *target = calloc(strlen(string1)+1, 1)
 strncpy(target, portion, 6);
 strncat(target, string1, 5);
 portion = target;    /* Sets portion to be HELLOPEOPLE */
```